# Reload or typing URL manually always redirect to root

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

The title says it all.

When I type a url manually in a browser or try to refresh, it always goes back to root, is there any thing wrong? because I'm not getting it.

When I refresh or type url manually and I'm logged in it goes to the dashboard, and when I'm not logged in, it goes to login page.

Here is my code

```
 import { Switch, Route, Redirect, Router } from 'react-router-dom';

 <Provider store={this.props.store}>
    <IntlProvider locale={this.props.locale} messages={this.props.localeData}>
      <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<Redirect to="/dashboard" />)} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={App} locale={this.props.locale} redirectTo="/login" />
            <PropsRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PropsRoute path="/reset-password" component={ResetPassword} />
            <PropsRoute path="/loader" component={Loader} spinning={true} fullScreen={true} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </LocaleProvider>
    </IntlProvider>
  </Provider>
```

this is my props route

```
const renderMergedProps = (component, ...rest) => {
  const finalProps = Object.assign({}, ...rest);
  return (
    React.createElement(component, finalProps)
  );
};

const PropsRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={routeProps => {
      return renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest);
    }} />
  );
};
```

and my private route

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ user, component, redirectTo, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={routeProps => {
      return user.logged ? (
        renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest)
      ) : (
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: redirectTo,
            state: { from: routeProps.location }
          }} />
        );
    }} />
  );
};
```

Note: I'm also using Redux and Redux Saga.

Answer (score 2):

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ user, component, redirectTo, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={routeProps => {
      return user.logged ? (
        renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest)
      ) : (
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: redirectTo,
            state: { from: routeProps.location }
          }} />
        );
    }} />
  );
};
```

Would say you should check if your user.logged hasn't change, it may be the case if your re-rendering the app when you manually change the url.
You could use localstorage to check if user is indeed logged or not.

Comment: Thank you Fabien, 
The problem is not in the PrivateRoute, even public routes always redirects to root even if I remove the PrivateRoute completely.
Also, the PrivateRoute is connected with Redux, so the `user.logged` is set on application load.